# Why do we need at least one class in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I created a new project in VSO. It automatically generated a class and a namespace. When I tried to run Main() function without any class and namespace, it failed.

Why do we need at least one class to run a program in C# ?

Comment: This is by design. The question you are asking is something like why do I need to use keys to start my car. As some cars allow starting by the push of a button, there are many languages that do not need class to be created (like C, C++, Basic, DBase, Fortran, Cobol, Assembly, Machine Language, etc)

Comment: Forget class ,namespace all those technical OOP words.Consider your operating system and Visual studio.To get into your code the one that you have written in Visual studio,you need a starting point,an entry point,just like home door,without door you cannot enter into the world of functions,pointers,datalayers etc(Giving/putting your program under the control of OS to ).So Static Void Main() is considered as entry point and to hold the door in a proper way a class is required.Thus door is an entry point and class holds the frame of the door.And so on the world of programming starts

Answer (score 0):

By analogy, this would be like asking why a C program must contain methods. It doesn't make any more sense to talk about a C# program without objects than it does to talk about a C program without methods.

As is the case with Java, C# is first and foremost an object-oriented program. In these languages a program is a collection of objects *by definition*. Even C#'s functional features are implemented in an object-oriented manner "under the hood."

Different programming paradigms are based on different models of what a program is. For example:

- Declarative: Collection of states
- Functional: Collection of functions (or, alternatively, the result of a computation).
- Object-oriented: Collection of interacting objects
- Imperative: Collection of algorithms

Note that languages will often mix paradigms to some degree. For example, C++ supports both imperative and object-oriented programming, and C# has many functional features.